# What is the proper way to index status history tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are using PostgreSql and have multiple tables which are laid out approximately like this.

1. A table for some entity in our system

```
apple

id | created_at | updated_at | user_id
```

2. An enum table with allowed values

```
quality

value (pk) | comment
---------------
okay       | ...
rotten     | ...
pristine   | ...
```

3. A status history table which records the status of that entity over time

```
apple_quality

id | created_at | updated_at | quality (fk) | apple_id (fk) | valid_at
```

4. A view on the status history table which gives the current status for each thing

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW current_apple_quality AS
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (apple_quality.apple_id) 
  apple_quality.id,
  apple_quality.created_at,
  apple_quality.updated_at,
  apple_quality.quality,
  apple_quality.apple_id,
  apple_quality.valid_at
FROM
  apple_quality
ORDER BY
  apple_quality.apple_id,
  apple_quality.valid_at DESC;
```

5. Indexes on

(in this example)

- `apple_quality.id`
- `apple_quality.apple_id`
- `apple_quality.apple_id, apple_quality.valid_at desc`

---

We are running in to issues where queries are needing to make a sequential scan of one of these status tables and its quite a bit too slow.

We are trying to ask questions akin to

"for a specific user, how many apples do they have which are rotten"

And our queries end up with a query plan that looks like this.

```
              ->  Aggregate  (cost=37256.06..37256.08 rows=1 width=32)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..37256.06 rows=1 width=8)
                          Join Filter: (apple.id = __be_0_current_apple_quality.apple_id)
                          ->  Subquery Scan on __be_0_current_apple_quality  (cost=0.42..37240.95 rows=544 width=16)
                                Filter: (__be_0_current_apple_quality.quality = 'rotten'::text)
                                ->  Unique  (cost=0.42..35880.96 rows=108799 width=113)
                                      ->  Index Scan using apple_quality_apple_id_valid_at_idx on apple_quality  (cost=0.42..34762.56 rows=447358 width=113)
```

So what I am wondering is

- Is there a better way to write the view which is more easily optimized?
- Are there indexes I should be adding?
- Is there anything else i can do to improve performance without denormalizing data?

This is a pattern we've used many places in our app, so I figure there might be some well known solutions/tradeoffs I don't have the experience to know about.

I can provide more information upon request.

Comment: How many apples does a user have? If the number is moderate, a function that uses PostgreSQL's substitute for an index skip scan would be best.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe 

Both apple and apple_quality have high numbers of items, but apple_quality is the one that we are having issues with. What is "PostgreSQL's substitute for an index skip scan"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I was asking about the number of apples *per user*, in the hope of finding an efficient solution for a single user. [The PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) has some examples how to emulate an index skip scan with recursive queries.

Comment: Many apples per user and a relatively large number of apples and apple_quality records. ~3 apple_quality records on average per apple.

I am reading that wiki page now, but its not clicking quite yet.

@LaurenzAlbe